# Java Socket nodes (Brokers) connect to nodes which are not yet alive

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Sockets related problem where I spawn 2 nodes, each node communicating with itself as well as the other nodes. The IPs of the nodes are located at a "brokers.txt" file which looks like this.

```
192.168.1.18:8080
192.168.1.18:8081
```

The first broker tries to connect to itself and succeeds but then tries to connect to the second and fails. Here is a detailed image of the connections which happen.

[image]

Each node has a Server listener which is a Thread, and a sender part which acts like a client which is not a thread  . Since it is not a thread, I cannot delay the sender part. Is there a way to wait until the Sender part starts its work without waiting?

For example, one possible solution would be to create a reconnect job which will happen asynchronously but I don't know if this is optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from output the problem gets larger and larger for bigger amount of socket nodes. For example if you had 3 nodes, the errors would be 3 and so on...
The unexpected behavior of threads is why you need to approach this problem differently without adding more difficult to understand code like reconnection jobs. The solution is as simple as going one step at a time, first you spawn the threads but not the sender part, you save each thread's instance, and finally you start the sender part anytime you want. This way each thread will be up and running which means it will be already listening.

This solution works however if you insist on the reconnection job you can follow this link:

https://dzone.com/articles/schedulers-in-java-and-spring